# Nuxt create a route without creating a page

Tags: vue.js, routes, vue-router, nuxt.js

I want to create a route (/logout) in nuxt without creating a page (.vue) for it.

In the past I would just create the route in my routes file and write some code in the enclosure.

Something like this in my nuxt config I thought would work but I get a not found

```
router: {
    routes: [
      {
        path: '/fish',
        redirect: to => {
          return { path: 'shark', query: null }
        }
      }
    ],

    middleware: 'auth'
  },
```

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

In your `nuxt` config file, you can leverage the `extendedRoutes` function off of the `router` object, something like this:

```
router: {
  extendedRoutes(routes, resolve) {
     routes.push({
       name: '',
       path: '',
       component: resolve(__dirname, 'pages/your/page.vue')
     })
  } 
}
```

Comment: Does this not still require a component?